# API response listener Playwright

Tags: typescript, testing, playwright

I want to assure that I don't have a password exposed in any of the network responses of my tests.

I was doing something like this
`await page.on('response', async response =>  console.log('<<', response.status(), response.url(), response.json()) );`
In beginning of my tests, but I can't get the response.json(), is returned this instead Promise {  }

Is there any other way?

Comment: First, you don't need to await `page.on`. It's not async. Second, you do need to await `response.json()`.